# Do non-EU consumers have EU consumer rights protection when buying from EU-registered companies?

Tags: european-union, consumer-protection

if consumer is citizen and resident of non EU Member State (e.g. Egypt) buy online service  from a company registered in EU, can this consumer use EU Consumer protection law? In particular 14 days cancellation period?